Masonryレイアウトを実現したい
コーディングについて質問です。
画像のようなレイアウトはどのようなHTML,cssで作れるのでしょうか。
box内はリストになっていて、アコーディオンの項目があったりなかったりで可変的です。
下記のcssだと2カラムにはなりますが、トップが2boxずつ揃ってしまいます。
ご教授いただけますと幸いです。
追記：
Masonryレイアウトということに辿り着いたのですが、HTMLでは実装できないのでしょうか？
親要素（全体）
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%; 
  margin: auto;

子要素（ボックス）
  height: auto;
  width: 47%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: auto;



(3)と(4)の順序は正しいですか？


Masonryレイアウトということに辿り着いたのですが、HTMLでは実装できないのでしょうか？

Masonry_layout を望んでいるのなら, Firefoxであれば可能です
参考: (developer.mozilla.org) メイソンリーレイアウト
"Limited availability" で示されているように, 基本的にはどの Webブラウザーも対応していないけれど
Firefoxであれば「実験的な機能」としてレイアウト可能

機能を有効化する
上記ページを開いてみる

有効化するには about:config を開き, layout.css.grid-template-masonry-value.enabled を trueへ
(layout.css.g のようにタイプすれば項目が出ます)


ご回答いただきありがとうございます！
そもそもイントラネットで使用したいのですが、実験的ということは使用しない方がいいでしょうか。。


イントラネット
「上記ページを開いてみる」と書いたのは, Masonry_layout の CSSサンブルとして適当なページが他にないからです。(他にあるとしたら大抵 JavaScript利用したものなど) 。 / 「実験的」については実験的 (experimental)のページをどうぞ


ご丁寧にありがとうございました。masonryの実装はできたのですが、再度問題が起きたので新たに質問させていただきました。ご回答いただけますと幸いでございます。
